# Wordpress Load more Posts on click (Solution)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Hello All This is a solution for Load more posts by wordpress ajax.

First of all suppose you have section like this.

```html
      <section class="hightech-news-content" >
      <div class="container">
        <?php
         $page_number = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $page_link =  get_pagenum_link(9999999999);
        $args = array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => 3,'paged'=>$page_number);
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $max_page = $the_query->max_num_pages;
    ?>      
       <div class="row news-list-row">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 hightech-news-list">
         <div class="row hightech-news-list-row">
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-4 hightech-news-list-img">
         <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>">
      <?php }else{ ?>     
          <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Img-1.png">
      <?php } ?>          
       <img class="hi_img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Hi.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-8 hightech-news-list-content">
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 80)."...";?></p>
       <br>
       <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">> Lee verder</a></h4>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif ;?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center loading-img">
    <img id="loading-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/loading.gif" >
    </div>
   <div class="event-more">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="load-more" onclick="loadMoreFun();" data-pagenumber="<?php echo $page_number; ?>" data-maxpage="<?php echo $max_page; ?>" data-pagelink="<?php echo $page_link; ?>">
   <h4><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/next.png" >Bekijk de agenda</h4>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Now for loadMoreFun() we can add a script like this.

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">
function loadMoreFun() {
 var next_page = jQuery('#load-more').data("pagenumber");
 var max_page = jQuery('#load-more').data("maxpage");
 var next_page_url = jQuery('#load-more').data("pagelink");
 var $load_more_btn = jQuery(this);
    var request_data = jQuery(this).attr('pagenumber');
    next_page++;
    jQuery('#load-more').data('pagenumber',next_page);
 var next_link = next_page_url.replace(/\d+(\/)?$/, next_page + '$1');
 if(next_page <= max_page) {
 var post_type = 'post'; 
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : next_link,
       cache: false,
       beforeSend: function(){
           jQuery('.loading-img').show();
       },
       complete: function(){
           jQuery('.loading-img').hide();
       },    
   success: function(response)  {
      if (jQuery(response).find('.hightech-news-list')){
       var newElems = jQuery(response).find('.news-list-row').html();
       jQuery('.news-list-row').append(newElems);
       if(next_page == max_page){
       jQuery('#load-more').text('No More News Available');
       }
      } else{
       
      }
  }
 });
 }
}
 </script>
```

Hope it will be helpful for everyone.Please let me know it another help required.